# Reference request: Abel or Ruffini's proof of the Abel-Ruffini theorem

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, galois-theory

The standard proof of the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) that people learn is based on Galois theory and the notion of a solvable group, but my understanding is that the original proof predates Galois theory. Where can I find a reasonably modern exposition of this original proof? Bonus points if it's online and free, of course.

Comment: Is galois-theory tag appropriate? (as you specifically don't want that).

Comment: In the  link you can find Jim Brown's paper about the theorem. http://www.math.caltech.edu/~jimlb/abel.pdf

Comment: Qiaochu, sorry to misappropriate this question: At [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118834/how-to-count-using-polynomials-when-we-have-subsets-that-partially-overlap), which is pretty much incomprehensible (to me), I suggested to post the question in Chinese in the hope that someone might translate it. Unfortunately noone has; I thought perhaps you might be able to help or make a useful suggestion to the OP how to deal with this language problem. (I wouldn't ordinarily assume that you speak Chinese from your name, but I read something that said you were born in China :-)

Comment: @joriki: unfortunately I cannot read Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend of mine is reading [Abel's Proof](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262661829) by Pesic. It seems to have what you're looking for and I think he is pretty happy with it. I can't personally vouch for it, though.

Comment: To be specific: *Abel's Proof* contains a full, commented translation of, well... Abel's proof, but not Ruffini's.